# Timeseries Pattern recognition

Tags: time-series, arima, pattern-recognition

I have about 8000 timeseries from kepler. 
Every timeseries is from another star. 
Every timeseries are classified into two classes (there is planet orbitting around star, there is no planet). 
X axis is time, Y is flux(amount of light emitted by star, registered by detector). 
Every star have about 6000 observations in time.

Below i placed two charts showing two timeseries. One with planet orbitted around star and not. 
It can be noticed that Star with oribtted planet is more periodic.

[Star with orbitting planet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BljUq.png)

[Start without planet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3pwV.png)

But some of sequences for star without planet is also strong periodic and seems as start with planet.

I'm looking for method, that I can calculate probability if unseen data sequence, point to star with orbitting planet.
ARIMA is probably bad solution because every next data point is independent from previous.

It is a good way to decompose data into trend and seasonality and trying find pattern, and in the last step compare it with unseen data? What can be best method for this? I can throw Sequences labeled as not planet with strong periodicity during fitting step. 
My goal is to discard stars where the certainty of the lack of a planet is high.
Or there is better way to achive this?

Comment: Intervention Detection could be useful to you. If you post some actual data I will try and help further. , See user:3382 intervention detection . If the observations are independent this is not a problem.

Comment: It is not plausible to use "interventions" to model observations related to regular planetary orbits unless you are concerned about possible sudden changes in the responses of the flux-measurement instrumentation.  Much more scientifically natural would be a Fourier analysis.  Have you tried that and found it somehow lacking?

Comment: I not try Fourier analysis yet. Do you suggest to try find clear harmonics occurring in observations ?